# Magento 2 SessionHandler error

Tags: magento2, session

Sometimes my magento 2 store returns this error

"Notice: SessionHandler::gc(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php5) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/vhosts/domain.net/httpdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php on line 110

it appear randomly and hard to reproduce unless it appear again. help me to solve this issue

Comment: you are not allowed to read/write on the folder `/var/lib/php5`

Comment: @Marius this error is from magento, so do I need set read/write permissions to `/var/lib/php5` folder ?